# How to fix appbar center widget in Modern shap devices

Tags: flutter, appbar

Nowadays there are many devices having different types of shaps, their screen is no more rectangular shape. some devices have a camera inside the screen area like a water drop from the middle of the plain surface.
Now how we can manage our app bar widget which has a center widget. SafeArea widget can only give useful when devices have corner edges.

```
AppBar(
  elevation: 0,
  title: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: isbgVisible
        ? Image.asset(
            'assets/logosmal_.png',
            scale: 1.5,
          )
        : Container(),
  ),
  centerTitle: true,
  actions: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/man.png',
          scale: 1.5,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
  backgroundColor: isbgVisible ? Constants.whiteColor : Colors.transparent,
  leading: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Constants.darkYello),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Modern Devices edge shap camera]

Comment: use safe area widget. above scafold

Comment: wrap it with safe area widget

Comment: I used safe area it does not work, it only supports when you have curve edges in screen. In my case screen you can see camera part of devices in inside the screen area

Answer (score 1):

**SafeArea** will be useful in that case:

**How to use**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: SafeArea(
     child: TonsOfOtherWidgets();
   ),
 ),
}
```

For more information. [visit here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkF0TQJO0bA)

Comment: I used safe area it does not work, it only supports when you have curve edges in screen. In my case screen you can see camera part of devices in inside the screen area